# Como retirar registros repetidos no SQL de acordo com o resultado de outra variável?

Tags: sql

Eu tenho tenho essa base:

| data | cargo | tempo_cargo | escola |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-22T20:55:37.427Z | 2 | 3 | BBBBBBBB |
| 2023-11-22T20:24:50.946Z | 1 | 3 | XXXXXXXX |
| 2023-12-12T19:35:17.365Z | 3 | 4 | XXXXXXXX |
| 2023-11-27T20:00:50.755Z | 2 | 2 | BBBBBBBB |

Precisamos ficar com a base sem escolas repetidas, para isso vamos aplicar a seguinte regra:

1. Situações em que as respostas repetidas de uma mesma escola foram feitas por profissionais com cargos diferentes da escola, considerar a seguinte ordem de prioridade
   para manter a resposta: (i) diretor(a); (ii) vice-diretor(a); (iii) professor
2. Situações em que as respostas repetidas da escola que foram recebidas sejam de pessoas no mesmo cargo, por exemplo, 2 vice-diretores,
   manter na base somente a resposta de quem está há mais tempo no cargo.

Como posso fazer isso no SQL para chegar nesse resultado?

| data | cargo | tempo_cargo | escola |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-22T20:55:37.427Z | 2 | 3 | BBBBBBBB |
| 2023-11-22T20:24:50.946Z | 1 | 3 | XXXXXXXX |

Comment: Neste caso, consegue colocar na pérgunta o resultado esperado, só para confirmar?

Comment: Claro. Adicionado!

Comment: Como deve ser feito para validar para quem está há mais tempo no cargo?

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de mudar o nome da variável

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível utilizar a função `row_number()` com *window function* para classificar os registros de uma mesma escola com base nos parâmetros que indicou e depois selecionar apenas o primeiro de cada grupo.

Para uma mesma escola precisamos ordenar pela coluna `cargo` de forma crescente e `tempo_cargo` de forma decrescente.

Fazendo:

```sql
SELECT 
  respostas.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY escola 
    ORDER BY cargo ASC, tempo_cargo DESC
  ) AS posicao
FROM respostas
```

O resultado será:

| data | cargo | tempo_cargo | escola | posicao |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-22T20:55:37.427Z | 2 | 3 | BBBBBBBB | 1 |
| 2023-11-27T20:00:50.755Z | 2 | 2 | BBBBBBBB | 2 |
| 2023-11-22T20:24:50.946Z | 1 | 3 | XXXXXXXX | 1 |
| 2023-12-12T19:35:17.365Z | 3 | 4 | XXXXXXXX | 2 |

Então basta fazer isso em uma sub-consulta e selecionar apenas o primeiro de cada grupo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        respostas.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY escola 
          ORDER BY cargo ASC, tempo_cargo DESC
        ) AS posicao
    FROM respostas
) AS ordenado
WHERE ordenado.posicao = 1
```

O resultado será:

| data | cargo | tempo_cargo | escola | posicao |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-22T20:55:37.427Z | 2 | 3 | BBBBBBBB | 1 |
| 2023-11-22T20:24:50.946Z | 1 | 3 | XXXXXXXX | 1 |

Existe a função `RANK()` com esse mesmo objetivo, porém ela permite empates entre dois ou mais registros quando as condições de ranqueamento são idênticas. Se no seu caso isso for possível para respostas com o mesmo grau de cargo e tempo no cargo ter que retornar ambas basta substituir, então, a função `ROW_NUMBER()` por `RANK()`.

Comment: Muito Obrigada!